# How to do interactive transition + ending animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiviewanimationtransition

Normally, we can do an interactive transitioning with `animateTransition` of `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and updating progress via `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.

**Question:**
How to have the interactive transitioning at first, then as we pass a certain threshold, perform a different ending animation?

What I want to achieve here is something like dismissing App store's Today card (https://gph.is/2qgcGHd). We can interactively shrink the card by panning a left edge of the screen. Then when it reaches the point, the card animates back to home page without any interactivity. It seems like a combination of interactive + animate transition to me.

---

**What I've tried:**
 I tried doing this in `UIView.animateWithKeyFrames` by dividing into two parts of animation with 0.5 relative times for each. Then as the progress reach 0.5, I call `finish()` (of `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`) to have the second animation performing. It has some glitches there and it's like a hack. Want to know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Apparently the API already accounts for a non-interactive part after the interactive part. Check out the docs for e.g. `completionCurve` and `completionSpeed`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollerinteractivetransitioning

Comment: @NicolasMiari Thanks for pointing out the doc. However, I want to do an entirely different completion animation after the interactive part. From the docs it seems like we can only specify `speed` and `curve`, is that right?

Comment: Havent read it through yet; perhaps there’s a way to structure your animation logic into segments to account for that... it’s just an idea, not really sure how to go about that. Haven’t used interactive transitions yet.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda have similar ideas, but still wanna see if there's a simpler/official way to go about this. But thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I use `UIView.animateKeyFrames`and dividing the interactive transition into two-part animation (as explained in the question):

```swift
let progressUntilDismissing = 0.4
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {

                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0,
                                   relativeDuration: progressUntilDismissing,
                                   animations: {
                        // interactive dismissing animation...
                })

                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: progressUntilDismissing,
                                   relativeDuration: (1 - progressUntilDismissing),
                                   animations: {
                        // closing dismissing animation...
                })
            }) { (finished) in
             //...
}
```

Then in the pan gesture recognizer, I calculate the pan progress and determine if it passes `progressUntilDismissing` or not.

If yes, call `finish()` on `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` subclass, it will animate the closing dismissing animation automatically.

In case anyone is curious, this is what I'm playing with:
[AppStoreTodayInteractiveTransition](https://github.com/aunnnn/AppStoreTodayInteractiveTransition)